# VUEX ROUTER nested children not rendering?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to get a child link from router to render so that the parent route stays active.

Here's my router:

```js
{
  path: '/portfolio',
  name: 'portfolio',
  component: () => import('./views/Portfolio.vue'),
  children: [
    {
      name: 'portfolioitems',
      path: '/portf/:id',
      component: () => import('./views/portf.vue')
    }
  ],
}
```

And my link on items to get page:

```html
<router-link :to="`/portfolio/portf/${items.id}`"> item </router-link>
```

The url does go to `/portfolio/portf/10` for example, but nothing renders on page.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you share code of your `Portfolio.vue` component?

Comment: Thanks, was missing <router-view>

Answer (score 0):

Replace `path: '/portf/:id',` with `path: 'portf/:id',` and let us know if it works. I faced the same issue before and the solution I am giving you worked for me. It might also work for you.

Comment: didn't seem to solve my issue. It redirects to the same path URL but stays on portfolio.vue instead of going to portf.vue.

Comment: It is supposed to stay on portfolio.vue. Child components are rendered within `<router-view>`. So in your portfolio.vue, you need somewhere another `<router-view></router-view>` and that is where your child component will be rendered. If oyu use child routes, you will always render the parent component and within that component, vue looks for a `<router-view>` to render the child.

Comment: Thank you @MatthiasS & p01ymath .. Thats what I was missing! Now I understand how it works!